# searchBar method doesn't work with my NSMutableArray (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

My app retrieves data in JSON format and displays it in a table view. I'm trying to implement a search method but the app crashes. Any ideas?

I can't seem to find any solutions that work.

**Update:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!isFiltered) {
        Product *productObject;
        productObject = [productsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = productObject.prodName;

        //Accessory.
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    } else {
        Product *productObject;
        productObject = [self.filteredProductNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Accessory.
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are filling the productsArray with objects type of Product

```
[productsArray addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProdID:pID andProdName:pName andProdDescription:pDescription andProdImage:pImage andProdManufacturer:pManufacturer andProdQuantity:pQuantity andProdPrice:pPrice]];
```

And then searching for NSString in it: `for (NSString *str in productsArray)`.

Correct way of searching would be when you create separate array containing list of items to be search. E.g Array of products name, or description.

Simple example to approach

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *filteredProductNameArray;
```

So here this property will store Array of product's name

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
NSMutableArray *productsNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
    self.filteredProductNameArray = self.productsArray; //If no str in textfield you should display all the data
}
else {
    isFiltered = YES;
    for (Product *product in self.productsArray) { //Because you have array type of Product, not NSString
        NSString *productName = product.name; //Or method to access `name` property of the Product class
        NSRange stringRange = [productName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [productsNameArray addObject:productName];
        }
    }
}
self.filteredProductNameArray = productsNameArray;
// Here you got array of products name which matches string in search bar textfield. And it is the actual products name list to be displayed
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here. And in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

}

You should check whether the name property of self.productsArray at indexPath.row equals to self.filteredProductNameArray;

I've left the further steps, but I guess you've got the idea and can complete by yourself. If you have any questions feel free to ask, I will try to help

Comment: Man! I just noticed a PROBLEM! The table view gets updated correctly, but when I press the row it's not the correct row that gets shown!

Comment: @Cuckoo can you post the code you use to configure UITableViewCell ? I think you either do not filter in  that method , or did not set table view row count correctly.

Comment: Your answer is no longer an accepted one :/ Please help me!

Comment: @Cuckoo created gist https://gist.github.com/hokim-m/c0645ed1413986ea8241b892648581f9

Comment: It doesn't work... Can I send you the project as a zip-file and you can take a look?

Comment: @Cuckoo No necessary uploading full project) Create a gist for a file where you got problem implementing, so I could leave comments and corrections

Answer (score 0):

Your app crashes because `productsArray` contains objects that are of type `Product` not NSString.

So in your for loop change this:

```
for (NSString *str in productsArray)
```

into this

```
for (Product *product in productsArray)
```

Then get the NSString property of the product. I think you mean `productName`

Comment: Down in the retrieveData method, the productArray gets filled with strings :/

Answer (score 0):

you are using two different NSMutableArray for retrieveData and searchBar, try to use same which you have used in Table row and creating cell.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the method you are using to fetch the JSON. dataWithContentsOfURL: should not be used for network-based URLs. [dataWithContentsOfURL:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl)

To fetch data over the network, take a look at [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession).

Where is it crashing exactly? I suggest putting in a break point and stepping through this code. That will probably be the easiest way to find the source.

Comment: It crashes when I start typing in the search bar :/

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Product rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17026a840'